# How to create a Global "Session"?

Tags: c#

I wanted to make a piece of `HTML` visible only if you have a certain Session. But as I understand Session shouldn't be global.

How do I do that anyways?

Comment: Why the `sql` tag? It has nothing to do with your question. Instead please add 1 or more tags to express which output technology you are using, e.g. MVC, Razor Pages, etc.

Comment: *Session* is a property of the web server technology - tag appropriately.